# Format string in python

Tags: python

I have to write one string as follows:

```
A = 55
B = 45

res = 'A =' + str(A) + '\n' + \
            'B = ' + str(B)
```

The A and B have to be separated into two lines.

```
print res
```

Result is correct. However, if i have other variables such as C,D,E, etc. doing one by one as in my code is difficult. What is shorter and easier way for doing it?

Comment: Do you mean that your variables will always be single character alphabet from A to Z max ?

Comment: net necessarily, the variable names may vary

Comment: Where are the variables defined? Are they within a function? Not that I recommend it, but could you hack something together with `locals()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
A = 45
B = 55
C = 65

names = ['A', 'B', 'C'] # list of variable names
res = '\n'.join([varname + ' =' + str(locals()[varname]) for varname in names])
```

This does what you've asked for, but if it's going to be used in a practical program I would look at other methods for storing and retrieving the data such as a dictionary.

Comment: `eval` can cause some serious issues if not used carefully.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan i am using this code zipping the names and values without using eval

Comment: Don't use `eval` when you have propper substitute - `globals()[varname]` (or, sufficient enough in this example, `locals`).

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, I've edited my answer to use `locals()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a dictionary of the values and iterate over it:

```
values = {
    'A': 56,
    'B': 32,
    'C': 34
}

res = ''
for key in values:
    res += key + ' = ' + str(values[key]) + '\n'
```

If you want to have the values in order, you should use an OrderedDict, as suggested in the answer by Peter Woods.

Comment: its more manual than mine. The given values are separated by variable names and not in the dictionary form

Comment: Well, I don't think it's possible to automate it in any way without grouping the variables somehow. You need to specify how to access the list of variables.

Comment: What order do the values come out?

Comment: It is true you should use an OrderedDict. Not sure if I should edit my answer to reflect that, cos I would feel like stealing from you, but perhaps I should for it to be correct.

Comment: @ralh Go ahead and edit your answer if you like. Not stealing, just make your answer the best you think you can. No shame in that (c:

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.format` to determine `res` easier:

```
res = 'A ={}\nB = {}'.format(A, B)
```

The `{}` are replaced with the parameters that you pass to `format` and you can pass in as many as you want.

Comment: This is shorter but it doesn't really answer the question. You still need to hand code the variable names into the format string.

Comment: @mhawke But you no longer need to add `+ str(var) +` for each one, which I believe is the OP's concern.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure what the main concern is... I think that OP is after something that will automate the insertion of the variable names into the output string too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process all your variables (e.g. you are in function) you can use `locals`

```
def f():
    A = 55
    B = 45
    C = 35
    D = 25
    print("\n".join("{} = {}".format(k, v) for k,v in locals().items()))
```

in action:

```
>>> f()
A = 55
B = 45
C = 35
D = 25
```

Otherwise we have to know which variables do you want to process - for example, use `OrderedDict`:

```
d = OrderedDict([
("A", 55),
("B", 45),
("C", 35),
("D", 25),
])

print("\n".join("{} = {}".format(k, v) for k,v in d.items()))
```

Comment: If you use kwargs, your ordering is lost.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't start variable names from uppercase. If you want to print all values you should have more usefull data structure. Like list or dictionary.

```
>>> dictionary = {'a':55, 'b':45, 'c':65}
>>> for key, value in dictionary.items():
...     print str(key) + ' = ' + str(value)
... 
a = 55
c = 65
b = 45
```

If you want to have sorted output, create a list of strings first:

```
>>> list = []
>>> for key, value in dictionary.iteritems():
...     list.append(str(key) + ' = ' + str(value))
... 
>>> list
['a = 55', 'c = 65', 'b = 45']
>>> for el in sorted(list):
...     print el
... 
a = 55
b = 45
c = 65
```